Apply to user control a style using converter with multiple values and value sources
I am working in Avalonia and have a user control (UC) whose IsVisible value I want to bind to properties of both its DataContext and that of the parent control.  In the parent control/view I have an instance of this UC both on its own, bound to a property of the parent DataContext, and as the DataTemplate of a WrapPanel-templated ItemsControl, bound to a property of each element of a collection.  Also, there are two such ItemsControls.  The "single" instance works as desired, hiding when its property is false and the parent property is true:
        <TabControl>
          <TabItem>
            <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>...
              <views:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding ParentVMUCMember}" Width="215" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <views:MyUserControl.IsVisible>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OrGateConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="!$parent[TabControl].((vm:ParentVM)DataContext).AreDeactivatedUCsHidden" />
                    <Binding Path="IsActivated" />
                  </MultiBinding>
                </views:MyUserControl.IsVisible>
              </views:MyUserControl>

Since all instances of the UC in this TabControl of the parent are to employ this mechanism and will look the same, I want to create a style to apply to all them that includes the IsVisible conversion.  I need the proper syntax, as this did not work:
          <TabControl.Styles>
            <Style Selector="views|MyUserControl">
              <Setter Property="Width" Value="215" />
              <Setter Property="Height" Value="200" />
              <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
              <Setter Property="IsVisible">
                <Setter.Value>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OrGateConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="!$parent[TabControl].((vm:ParentVM)DataContext).AreDeactivatedUCsHidden" />
                    <Binding Path="IsActivated" />
                  </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
            </Style>
          </TabControl.Styles>

It gives me the error:
AVLN2000    Unable to resolve property or method of name 'IsActivated' on type 'Project.ViewModels.ParentVM'
If I change it to <Binding Path="$self.IsActivated" />, I get the same error, but on "type 'Project.ViewModels.MyUserControl'".
The parent TabControl's full AXAML is below, in case that's important:
    <TabControl>
      <TabControl.Styles>
        <Style Selector="views|MyUserControl">
          <Setter Property="Width" Value="215" />
          <Setter Property="Height" Value="200" />
          <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        </Style>
      </TabControl.Styles>
      <TabItem Header="Single and one on ItemsControl">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <views:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding ParentVMUCMember}">
            <views:MyUserControl.IsVisible>
              <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OrGateConverter}">
                <Binding Path="!$parent[TabControl].((vm:ParentVM)DataContext).AreDeactivatedUCsHidden" />
                <Binding Path="IsActivated" />
              </MultiBinding>
            </views:MyUserControl.IsVisible>
          </views:MyUserControl>
          <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ParentVMFirstCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel UseLayoutRounding="True" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <views:MyUserControl>
                  <views:MyUserControl.IsVisible>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OrGateConverter}">
                      <Binding Path="!$parent[TabControl].((vm:ParentVM)DataContext).AreDeactivatedUCsHidden" />
                      <Binding Path="IsActivated" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                  </views:MyUserControl.IsVisible>
                </views:MyUserControl>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem Header="The second ItemsControl">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ParentVMSecondCollection}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <views:MyUserControl>
                <views:MyUserControl.IsVisible>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OrGateConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="!$parent[TabControl].((vm:ParentVM)DataContext).AreDeactivatedUCsHidden" />
                    <Binding Path="IsActivated" />
                  </MultiBinding>
                </views:MyUserControl.IsVisible>
              </views:MyUserControl>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
      </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

I would like to replace all 3 MultiBindings with the application of a Style like what failed.  Much appreciation for any help...
